# Why do some apps leave KeyRelease events to be consumed by next focused app/window

Tags: scripting, x11, xorg, dmenu

I'm trying to wrap [dmenu](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/) within some script to feed it input and act on it, however when pressing the Return key to select some dmenu input, a KeyRelease event gets sent to whatever window is focused when dmenu closes.
If that app reacts to it (in my case it happened with javascript in firefox) unwanted things may happen.

But this is not specific to my script or even dmenu. It also happens with other dialog style X apps that I tested, in particular ssh-askpass, ksshaskpass, the gpg passphrase dialog, etc.

A simple test is the following:

1. Bind ssh-askpass to a key(combination). I use my i3-wm configuration for that.
2. Run the following in a terminal:

   ```
   xev | grep -EA2 --line-buffered '^Key(Press|Release)' | sed -n 's/^.*\(Press\|Release\|keysym[^)]*\).*$/\1/p'
   ```
3. Press the bound key combination.
4. Press Return, observe the following output in the terminal:

   ```
   Release
   keysym 0xff0d, Return
   ```
5. Do not observe a previous `Press` of `Return`

Why do those apps not consume the `Release` from the X event queue? I would argue a bug - but in X or in the app?

When wrapping such an app with a (python?) script, how can I fix this?

Comment: Hmmm. I can't really fault the dialog box for not staying around until the key is released (why would it? I expect the button to respond to pressing Enter, not to releasing it). I can't fault X11 for allowing a focus change between a KeyPress event and KeyRelease: this wouldn't make sense for modifiers, for once. I do fault Firefox or that piece of JS for reacting to the KeyRelease event: an application should not normally do this, and certainly not trigger an action on a KeyRelease event for which it didn't get the KeyPress.

Comment: You are right, the JS code is broken. However, I would argue, that since the dialog handled the KeyPress, it should also consume the KeyRelease for two reasons:
1. Cleanup and sanity - it handled the key, the user "wanted" the action that the dialog assigned to it, the user most likely does not want the key release to have any other action in possible any other open window.
2. Consistency - a mouse click on the "ok" button in ssh-askpass for example, only triggers on release.
The first argument could hold for X11 as well, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

An application that has handled a `KeyPress` event is not generally expected to handle the subsequent `KeyRelease` event. If the user presses a key, then switches to another application, and then releases the key, then the focus change is expected to happen when requested, it is not supposed to be delayed until the user has released the key.

X11's architecture for handling input events is pretty simple: either the event has been grabbed by a client, in which case the client receives the event, or the event hasn't been grabbed, in which case the client that currently has the focus receives the event. There is no provision to dispatch `KeyRelease` events separately on the basis of which client received the `KeyPress` event.

An example where it would clearly be wrong to re-route `KeyRelease` events to the client that received the `KeyPress` is with modifiers. On a focus change, if a modifier is pressed, it remains pressed. The `KeyRelease` event is sent when the modifier is no longer pressed. While it could make sense to send `KeyRelease` events for all depressed modifiers on a focus loss and send corresponding `KeyPress` events to the newly-focused window, that wouldn't be an accurate report of the actual user input, which would be especially disruptive for focus changes between widgets of the same application.

Another example where the X11 behavior is clearly right and your proposal of re-routing keypress events would be wrong is with focus changes between widgets of the same application. It would be wrong to send spurious events if the application cares about this particular key without caring which widget was focused. But if the application does care about which widget receives the `KeyRelease` event, then this event should definitely be sent to the widget that has the focus at the time.

Most applications have actions triggered by key press events, not by key release events. When an event causes a button to be pressed, the button's effect is expected to be triggered at the time of the press, not at the time of the release. It would be a strange user experience if events causing the closure of a window behaved differently.

An example where it is clearly the right thing to let the focus be transferred to another window when a key press has caused the closure of a window is keeping the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key held down to exit multiple dialog boxes. It would be disruptive if an application required releasing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to be released to close a window.

In the scenario you describe, it's clearly the Firefox/JavaScript application that's doing something wrong. Most keyboard interfaces are based on key presses, not on key releases. In particular, it's *pressing* <kbd>Enter</kbd> that's supposed to cause something to happen, not *releasing* it. If an application reacts to a key release event, the onus is on it to handle situations where it receives a `KeyRelease` event without having received a matching `KeyPress` in a sensible manner.

Mouse clicks are somewhat different because there are many situations where an interface is expected to react to release events, such as drag-and-drop or events that depend on the duration of a click. Even then, an application should generally not react to a `ButtonRelease` event if it didn't get the corresponding `ButtonPress`.

Comment: Well, I can follow and accept that reasoning. However, at least in my use case, it will never be acceptable for any other application to receive the `KeyRelease` - it can only cause unintentional behaviour. It seems to be very common for JS to handle `KeyRelease`(`keyup`), especially in login fields. 

So I would like to somehow grab it from the event queue, such that it cannot be passed anywhere else. I tried to manipulate the queue from my python wrapper script, but did not understand the X API well enough to succeed.

Comment: @Klaas I think you could grab the KeyRelease event before sending the KeyPress event. Or maybe you can send a KeyPress event to the intended window, then send a KeyRelease event to some dummy window created by your sciprt.